# AWS services- enable another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloud9

What is the best way to replicate the services like lambda, sns, cloudwatchrules, S3, from an existing region(us-east-1) to another region(singapore) other than using cloudformation template?

Comment: IMO CloudFormation is the best AWS-native way to do all this - it's worth investing the time to learn it - if you don't like the JSON/YAML files, you should have a look at [Sparkleformation](https://www.sparkleformation.io/) or the [AWS Cloud Development Kit](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk) (CDK), which is currently in Beta.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is always to use AWS APIs in one way or the other from writing simple shell scripts to cloudformation and also by using Terraform.  Using the AWS console and migrating is a nightmare.

Please note that it is always better to move to IAAC (Infrastructure as a Code).

Also the same process cannot be used for every AWS service for migration. For this AWS has a [whitepaper](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AWS_Migrate_Resources_To_New_Region.pdf) which lists the steps of migration from one region to another.